# Slider with zoom and movement effect

Tags: css, slider

I’m trying to build a css only Slider with zoom effect.

The thing I’m not able to do is to difference the zoom from one slide to the other. For example I would like the first slide to have the current zoom effect but going slowly from right to left, the second from left to right and the third from top to bottom.
Any help?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/53gpxtk1/) is the Jsfiddle

```
<div class="pic-wrapper">
<figure class="pic-1"></figure>
<figure class="pic-2"></figure>
<figure class="pic-3"></figure>
<figure class="pic-4"></figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated my answer, it should work on opera to now.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by setting the property `background-position` in your animation.

I added `background-position: 0px 0px;` to `slideShow { 0% {}` and  `background-position: -400px 0px;` to  `slideShow { 100% {}`.

Now the image moves slowly to the left.

```css
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 .pic-wrapper {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 figure {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     opacity: 0;
    /*animation*/
     animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
     -o-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
     -moz-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
     -webkit-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
}
 figurecaption {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     color: #fff;
}
 .pic-1 {
     opacity: 1;
     background: url(https://c.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/4223-SUZUKIJIMNYTHEONE-AND-ONLYSMALLLIGHTWEIGHT4WDVEHICLE-980x620.jpg) no-repeat center center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
}
 .pic-2 {
     animation-delay: 6s;
     -o-animation-delay: 6s;
     -moz--animation-delay: 6s;
     -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
     background: url(https://c.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/4223-SUZUKIJIMNYTHEONE-AND-ONLYSMALLLIGHTWEIGHT4WDVEHICLE-980x620.jpg) no-repeat center center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
}
 .pic-3 {
     animation-delay: 12s;
     -o-animation-delay: 12s;
     -moz--animation-delay: 12s;
     -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
     background: url(https://c.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/4223-SUZUKIJIMNYTHEONE-AND-ONLYSMALLLIGHTWEIGHT4WDVEHICLE-980x620.jpg) no-repeat center center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
}
 .pic-4 {
     animation-delay: 18s;
     -o-animation-delay: 18s;
     -moz--animation-delay: 18s;
     -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
     background: url(https://c.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/4223-SUZUKIJIMNYTHEONE-AND-ONLYSMALLLIGHTWEIGHT4WDVEHICLE-980x620.jpg) no-repeat center center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
}
/* keyframes*/
 @keyframes slideShow {
     0% {
         background-position: 0px 0px;
         opacity: 0;
         transform:scale(1);
         -ms-transform:scale(1);
    }
     5% {
         opacity: 1 
    }
     25% {
         opacity: 1;
    }
     30% {
         opacity: 0;
         transform:scale(1.1);
         -ms-transform:scale(1.1);
    }
     100% {
         background-position: -400px 0px;
         opacity: 0;
         transform:scale(1);
         -ms-transformm:scale(1);
    }
}
 @-o-keyframes slideShow {
     0% {
         background-position: 0px 0px;
         opacity: 0;
         -o-transform:scale(1);
    }
     5% {
         opacity: 1 
    }
     25% {
         opacity: 1;
    }
     30% {
         opacity: 0;
         -o-transform:scale(1.1);
    }
     100% {
         background-position: -400px 0px;
         opacity: 0;
         -o-transformm:scale(1);
    }
}
 @-moz-keyframes slideShow {
     0% {
         background-position: 0px 0px;
         opacity: 0;
         -moz-transform:scale(1);
    }
     5% {
         opacity: 1 
    }
     25% {
         opacity: 1;
    }
     30% {
         opacity: 0;
         -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
    }
     100% {
         background-position: -400px 0px;
         opacity: 0;
         -moz-transformm:scale(1);
    }
}
 @-webkit-keyframes slideShow {
     0% {
         background-position: 0px 0px;
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    }
     5% {
         opacity: 1 
    }
     25% {
         opacity: 1;
    }
     30% {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
    }
     100% {
         background-position: -400px 0px;
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transformm:scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-wrapper">
  <figure class="pic-1"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-2"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-3"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-4"></figure>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/53gpxtk1/23/